# Read a Int64 in an ArrayBuffer using DataView

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer

I am using Web Sockets.

I am passing an ArrayBuffer to my JavaScript page.

I have this in C# code:

```
 byte[] packet = new byte[2];
 packet[0] = (byte)1;
 packet[1] = (byte)0;

 byte[] tickArray = BitConverter.GetBytes( 635744635349556838 );
 byte[] packet2 = new byte[2 + tickArray.Length];
 Buffer.BlockCopy(packet, 0, packet2, 0, packet.Length);
 Buffer.BlockCopy(tickArray, 0, packet2, packet.Length, tickArray.Length);
```

In my JavaScript Client I have this:

```
 var dv = new DataView(e.data);
 var marker = dv.getInt8(0);
 var tripped = dv.getInt8(1);

 var x = dv.getInt8(2);
```

I get the results:

```
1
0
-29
```

if change to this:

```
var x= dv.getInt16(1);

-7389
```

How do I get my value of 635744635349556838?

Thanks

Comment: actually with javascript `635744635349556838 == 635744635349556900` if you can send it as string. What does `e.data` output with a `console.log` ?

Comment: Hi, yes, I was looking into doing that. This number I am using is the UTC tick of the server.  I am assuming the length can change over time. Also, this byte array is put at the beginning of a larger byte array before being sent to the client(s). It is this varying length of string that will task me

Comment: FWIW, your value exceeds [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).

Comment: @robertklep Thanks, I came to the same result myself. I had to convert number to string and then use the length of as my header in int16

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a code. Would be it helpful?

```
function getUint64(bytes, littleEndian)
{
  var low = 4, high = 0;
  if (littleEndian)
  {
    low = 0;
    high = 4;
  }

  var dv = new DataView(Uint8Array.from(bytes ).buffer);

  return (dv.getUint32(high, littleEndian) << 32) |
        dv.getUint32(low, littleEndian);
}
    var bytes = [ 124, 22, 124, 22, 124, 22, 124, 22];
    var value = getUint64(bytes, false);
    console.log(value);
```

Comment: Oh wait lol that doesn't work at all. You clearly didn't test that code. The | operator just gives you int32. So does "<<" and every other bit operator. If you want to combine them, you need to use + and *